# SQL exception: No suitable driver while using MS JDBC in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, sql-server, jdbc

I'm trying using MS JDBC to connect to my SQL Server database but encountering this error.
java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver

Here is my code

```
@SuppressLint("NewAPI")
public void Connect() throws Exception {
    StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
    StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
    connection = null;
    String S_url = null;
    String driver = null;
    try {
        DriverManager.registerDriver(new com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver());
        driver = "com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver";
        Class.forName(driver);
        S_url = "jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://" + ip + ";"
                + "databaseName=" + db + ";user=" + un + ";password="
                + pass + ";";
        connection = DriverManager.getConnection(S_url);
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

I already added a .jar file into my project 
[Jar file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AuSW6.png)

And set a dependency
[Dependencies setting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fM8Dt.png)

Really appreciate your help and sorry if my English bother you, it's not my native language

Answer (score 1):

Remove the `jtds:` from your JDBC URL that you assign to `S_url`. You register a Microsoft driver, but use the [URL format of a jTDS driver](http://jtds.sourceforge.net/faq.html#urlFormat).